# Remove access to GitHub private repos

Tags: git, github

I have logged in my GitHub account using gh via https on a server, and now I don't have access to that server. So now I want to remove the access to my GitHub account on this server, so that the users on this server cannot clone my private repo anymore.

I have changed my GitHub account password, but I can still git clone my private repos and git push on another server on which I have logged my GitHub account previously. I have also created tokens, but this could not stop git cloning on servers with https credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all of the sessions you've discussed are HTTPS, then changing your password and PATs should cut off any future access from the server in question. You can also visit https://github.com/settings/sessions and forcibly end sessions.

In the future, though, you can manage this much more easily with SSH - generate a fresh keypair for each device, and if you ever want to revoke a specific device's access then all you have to do is revoke access for that public key.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I have changed my password and PATs, but I can still use git clone to access my private repos on a laptop with github credentials...

Comment: Git clone using HTTPS, or Git clone using SSH? This is a remarkably important detail.

Comment: I used HTTPS to authorize the git (using gh).